# Every locally finite collection is also point finite

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

We are given the following two definitions for a collection $\mathscr{U} = \{U_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in A}$ of subsets of a topological space $X$.

> $\mathscr{U}$ is **locally finite** if every point $x\in X$ has neighborhood that meets finitely many $U_\alpha$

and

> $\mathscr{U}$ is **point finite** if every point $x\in X$ lies in only finitely many $U_\alpha$

My textbook claims that it's apparent that every locally finite collection is also point finite without proof.

However, let's consider the collection of open intervals $\{(n, n+1) : n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ under the usual topology.

Is this set not locally finite? For any any $r \in \mathbb{R}$, we consider the the neighborhood $U_r = (r-\frac{1}{4}, r+\frac{1}{4})$. Then clearly $U_r$ can only meet at most $2$ of those open intervals. However, this collection is not point finite since $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ is not contained in any of those open intervals.

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Your collection **is** point-finite: each real number is contained in either $0$ or $1$ of them, and $0$ and $1$ are both finite.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Ahhhh, thanks so much.

Comment: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your collection *is* point finite. Each $n\in\mathbb Z$ belongs to zero of those intervals, and therefore the set of intervals to which $n$ belongs is emtpy. And $\emptyset$ is a finite set.

Answer (score 0):

The omitted prooflet:

Let $\mathcal{U}$ be a locally finite collection.

Let $x \in X$. Then by local finiteness we have $O(x)$,an open neighbourhood of $x$, such that $$\{U \in \mathcal{U}\mid U \cap O(x) \neq \emptyset \}\text{ is finite. }$$

But as $$\{U \in \mathcal{U}: x \in U\} \subseteq \{U \in \mathcal{U}\mid U \cap O(x)\neq \emptyset \}$$ because if $x \in U$ for sure $O(x) \cap U \neq \emptyset$, the former set is also finite and so $\mathcal{U}$ is point-finite. Your example shows that the inclusion can be strict: for $n \in \Bbb N$ the left hand set is finite and the right hand one has 2 elements. Both finite sets. No contraction..

You example family is both locally finite *and* point finite.